# get unique tags and number of occurrences from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

there is a "post" table in mysql and column "tags".

Tags' value is like *apple,orange,peach,etc.*

I'm trying to get all the tags and assign tag & number of occurances to array using php. Here is what I am trying to do.

```
$recmostusedtagscol = array();
$recmostusedtagsq = mysqli_query($connecDB,"select tags from post limit 5");
while($recmostusedtagsr = mysqli_fetch_array($recmostusedtagsq)){
  $tagsarray = explode(',', $recmostusedtagsr['tags']);
  foreach ($tagsarray as $tag) {
    if(in_array($tag,$recmostusedtagscol)){
      $recmostusedtagscol[$tag][]++;
    }
    else {
      $recmostusedtagscol .= [$tag => 1];
    }
  }
}
print_r($recmostusedtagscol);
```

**UPDATED:**
this one is close. It is listing uniqe values, but it is not adding plus 1 to the array value.

```
$recmostusedtagscol = array();
$recmostusedtagsq = mysqli_query($connecDB,"select tags from post");
while($recmostusedtagsr = mysqli_fetch_array($recmostusedtagsq)){
  $tagsarray = explode(',', $recmostusedtagsr['tags']);
  foreach ($tagsarray as $tag) {
    if(in_array($tag,$recmostusedtagscol)){
      $recmostusedtagscol[$tag]++;
    }
    else {
      $recmostusedtagscol[$tag]=1;
    }
  }
}
print_r($recmostusedtagscol);
```

it seems in_array() is not working.... maybe....

Comment: Why don't you sum that in SQL and retrieve the result once instead of iterating through the raw result?

Comment: `$recmostusedtagscol .= [$tag => 1];` turns that variable into a string.

Comment: This also makes zero sense: `$recmostusedtagscol[$tag][]++;`...

Comment: Why don't you normalize your datatables properly, then this would be a very simple SQL query

Comment: And don't use string concatenation when adding new entries to an array (`$recmostusedtagscol .= [$tag => 1];`).... arrays aren't strings... change `$recmostusedtagscol .= [$tag => 1];` to `$recmostusedtagscol[$tag] = 1;` and `$recmostusedtagscol[$tag][]++;` to `$recmostusedtagscol[$tag]++;` and `if(in_array($tag,$recmostusedtagscol)){` to `if(isset($recmostusedtagscol[$tag])){`

Comment: @arkascha can you check updated? I'm close

Comment: You missed one of my changes: `if(in_array($tag,$recmostusedtagscol)){` to `if(isset($recmostusedtagscol[$tag])){`... `in_array()` searches the ___values___ of the array (which are the count values for your array), ___not the keys___ (which are the tags in your case)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, here is the working one.

```
$recmostusedtagscol = array();
$recmostusedtagsq = mysqli_query($connecDB,"select tags from post");
while($recmostusedtagsr = mysqli_fetch_array($recmostusedtagsq)){
  $tagsarray = explode(',', $recmostusedtagsr['tags']);
  foreach ($tagsarray as $tag) {
    if(isset($recmostusedtagscol[$tag])){
      $recmostusedtagscol[$tag]++;
    }
    else {
      $recmostusedtagscol[$tag]=1;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks to @Mark Baker and @arkascha